# Align span of text vertically in table cell

Tags: html, css

How can I align vertical  text, that is generated by two spans, inside a div inside a table cell. I've tried many combinations of text-align,display but nothing worked. I have this html segment

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container">
                <span>This is span-sentence-1</span>
                 <span>This is span-sentence-2</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the output is

```
This is span-sentence-1 This is span-sentence-2
```

while I want to be rendered like this

```
This is span-sentence-1
This is span-sentence-2
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hjuxdd1b/1/

Comment: You should make the span display block, span{display:block}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*height: 50px; Remove height*/
}

.container span{
    display: block;/*Set display to  block*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hjuxdd1b/6/)

Comment: Thx it works. I didn't thought that it would be so simple. I tried to make the outer div display to block but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: block` to `.container span`

```
.container span {display: block;}
```

Remove the `height` and `line-height` in the `.container`

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/hjuxdd1b/7/

Answer (score 0):

You may not need that div:

- Set those spans to `display: block` so they are each given their own line.
- Give `vertical-align: middle` to the td so that its content will stay vertically centred.

[Have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/21w798ba/1/)

By default a span is `display: inline` so they will line up next to each other. You could [read more about the span element over on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

CSS

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td span {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <span>This is span-sentence-1</span>
            <span>This is span-sentence-2</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add br tag after the first span or replace span with div.